# Limits of a distribution property

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've been cracking my brains since several days so far trying to solve this exercise. I'll firstly claim the problem and then will clarify what I know and what I've tried to do.

So, we are given a real-valued r.v. on some probability space s.t. $\mathbb E(|X|)<\infty$ and by $F$ we denote the distribution function.
What we need to show is
$$\lim_{z \ \rightarrow \ - \ \infty}z F(z) = \lim_{z \ \rightarrow \ + \ \infty}z (1-F(z)) = 0$$

We know, that $\lim_{z \ \rightarrow \ - \ \infty}F(z) = 0$ and $\lim_{z \ \rightarrow \ + \ \infty}F(z) = 1$ and what I though of was to somehow show that the distribution function increases to $1$ faster than $z$ goes to infinity. Also, on this step we still don't know whether a density exists (it will be mentioned later in the exercise).

I realize that the solution might be quite simple but I'm really stuck with it.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How is the expectation value defined if you didn't define densities yet?

Comment: Can't it be defined via Lebesgue integral even if the density doesn't exist?   I guess we don't need the density then.

Comment: That's not my point. My point was that your proof will have to start from the definition of the expectation value and the fact that you required it to be finite.

Comment: For the case where $X$ has a density, see my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624189/since-mathbbex-is-defined-as-the-integral-from-0-to-infinity-of-sx/1626154#1626154

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It suffices to prove that $$\tag{*}\lim_{z\to +\infty}z\Pr\left(\left|X\right|\gt z\right)=0,$$
since the two wanted limits are up to a constant that of $z\Pr\left(X\gt z\right)$ and $z\Pr\left(-X\gt z\right)$ as $z$ goes to $+\infty$.

The convergence (*) follows from Markov's inequality: 
$$z\Pr\left(\left|X\right|\gt z\right) \leqslant \mathbb E\left[\left|X\right|\mathbf 1\left\{\left|X\right| \gt z\right\}\right]$$
and then use monotone convergence.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I though of applying Markov's inequality but wasn't able to come up with a decent way to do so. The only question I have for now is why do we need an indicator function in there since the inequality holds without it, right ? I realize that it is a crucial step here in terms of showing that the limit of expectation is 0 and then applying monotone convergence.

Comment: Without the indicator, we only have boundedness of $z\Pr\left(\left|X\right|\gt z\right)$ with respect to $z$.

Comment: Could you please verify that the following calculations are correct: $$\lim_{z\rightarrow-\infty}\mathbb E\left[\left|X\right|\mathbf 1_\left\{\left|X\right| \gt z\right\}\right] = \mathbb E\lim_{z\rightarrow-\infty}\left[\left|X\right|\mathbf 1_\left\{\left|X\right| \gt z\right\}\right] = \mathbb E\left|X\right|\lim_{z\rightarrow-\infty}\mathbf 1_\left\{\left|X\right| \gt z\right\} = 0$$
while $\lim_{z\rightarrow-\infty}\mathbf 1_\left\{\left|X\right| \gt z\right\} = 0$

Comment: You should replace the limit at $-\infty$ by the limit at $+\infty$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've just copied the limit code from my first post and forgot about the minus. Thanks a lot !